# Css: How to add background color and overlay content on picture tag?

Tags: html, css

Basically I am trying to add a background color and some text over the image and center the content div. 
As you can see on the screenshot, currently image takes only the 1/3 of the screen, but it should be full width. 
[image]

What I am trying to achieve is below the screenshot.
[image]
I tried to make use of `background-blend-mode: normal;` or apply `width:100%` or `aspect-ratio: 1/1` or `flex:1` but image is still not full width.
What I mean by that, is that image should be of the same width as the parent `container`.
[Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/picture-nos076) and code snippet below

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: #13293d;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  column-gap: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.picture-container {
  opacity: 0.1;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.content {
  opacity: 1;
  background-blend-mode: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="picture-container">
        <picture>
          <source
            media="(min-width:650px)"
            srcset="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm2og.png"
          />
          <img
            src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm2og.png"
            alt="Flowers"
          />
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p class="text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente
        </p>
      </div>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You probably need to set the img width to 100% instead of auto.

Comment: @ItagakiFumihiko thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't add the background color over the the whole container. I removed that style for less confusion.

Comment: Add .picture-container img { width: 100%; } How is it?

Answer (score 0):

set the img **width to 100vw** in css and remove **"style="width: auto;"** from html img element.

**lang-css file**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #13293d;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  column-gap: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.picture-container {
  opacity: 0.1;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
.picture-container img {
  width: 100vw;
}

.content {
  opacity: 1;
  background-blend-mode: normal;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**lang-html file**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="picture-container">
        <picture>
            <source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm2og.png" />
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm2og.png" alt="Flowers" />
        </picture>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Unfortunately as you see, the content paragraph and the background color are still under the picture, but not over it, you just made the picture full width, but they are still separate.  
Check in the dev tools and you will see what i mean.

Comment: see the screenshot please, I updated my post with the screenshot what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

for image use to show in center  `display: flex,margin:0px auto` 
then the image will be showing in the center
if you want to show the image full screen then use widht:100%

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. 
Please test first before asnwering.  It doesn't set the content over the image and background color also is not over the image. The image is still on top on the content div.